# Is it possible to perform NSBatchUpdateRequest with an array of NSManagedObjectID?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

Currently, I perform multiple update operations via the following code.

```
func updateOrders(_ updates : [(objectID: NSManagedObjectID, order: Int64)]) {
    if updates.isEmpty {
        return
    }
    
    let coreDataStack = CoreDataStack.INSTANCE
    let backgroundContext = coreDataStack.backgroundContext

    backgroundContext.perform {
        for update in updates {
            let objectID = update.objectID
            let order = update.order
            let nsPlainNote = try! backgroundContext.existingObject(with: objectID) as! NSPlainNote
            nsPlainNote.order = order
        }
        RepositoryUtils.saveContextIfPossible(backgroundContext)
    }
}
```

Since I would like to

- Make the update operations run faster
- Avoid delegate of `NSFetchedResultController` from being notified

I would like to utilise `NSBatchUpdateRequest` for performing such update operation.

However, I don't find a way, how I can apply array of `NSManagedObjectID` and array of `Int64` value, to `NSBatchUpdateRequest`.

Given an array of `NSManagedObjectID` and `Int64`, is it possible to use `NSBatchUpdateRequest` to perform updated on CoreData?

Answer (score 0):

You must use `NSPredicate` to set object id

```swift
func updateOrders(_ updates : [(objectID: NSManagedObjectID, order: Int64)]) {
    updates.forEach {
        let request = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "NSPlainNote")
        request.propertiesToUpdate = ["order": $0.order]
        request.predicate = NSPredicate(format: "objectID == %@", $0.objectID)
        let result = try? context.execute(request)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`NSBatchUpdateRequest` is not suitable for your task since using it makes sense for large amount of records with a common attribute's value so that you can filter all by your criteria and update all fields with your values at once.

The fact is that the `NSBatchDeleteRequest` is an `NSPersistentStoreRequest` which operates at the SQL level in the persistent store itself and it doesn't update your in-memory objects after execution thats why it works so fast and **Core Data** translates your native requests to a SQL ones where you can not use dynamically code to get and insert needed data from dictionary etc. but you can update the current value of a filed e.g.:

```swift
let batchRequest = NSBatchUpdateRequest(entityName: "Note")
batchRequest.predicate = predicate
// Increase `order` value
batchRequest.propertiesToUpdate = ["order" : NSExpression(format: "order + 1")]
do {
    try context.execute(batchRequest)
}
catch {
    fatalError(error.localizedDescription)
}
```